# Can someone promote their text-to-speech application that has public figures voices?

Tags: comparative-law, artificial-intelligence, right-of-publicity, romania

Let’s supposed that we have a Text-To-Speech site with public figures voices and we want to make some videos in order to promote it.

Our country legislation includes presumed consent for people that work in public information so that could allow us to make the site legally.

Now, when it comes to promoting it, could we present the functionality of it in a legal manner by having the link in bio of maybe showing the site that was used for converting the text to voice at the end of the video?

*The only consent that we have is the presumed one.
** We are also looking to monetise the TTS.

Edit:
The law I was referring to is from [Romanian civil code](https://lege5.ro/Gratuit/gezdmnrzge/art-76-prezumtia-de-consimtamant-codul-civil?dp=gqytsnzsge3dg):

> When the person to whom an information or material refers makes it available to a natural person or legal entity that he knows is carrying out his activity in the field of public information, consent for their use is presumed, no written agreement being necessary.

Comment: You would need to at least name your country and which law gives you this "presumed consent". I don't think you will get any good answers on theoretical laws we don't really know. What does the GDPR or alternative-dispute-resultion have to do with any of it?

Comment: You may also get in legal trouble if you market it in an app-store, assuming that there is no "your specific country"-appstore, but maybe the US or EU one you will want to use. Something may be legal in your country, but that doesn't mean Apple or Google have to help you sell it through their stores.

Comment: I just edited the question fell free to review it again. Thank you for your time! @nvoigt